# Complex SQL query with group by and having

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a table orders

```
orders (
id  int unsigned not null,
fcr_date  TIMESTAMP,
completion_date TIMESTAMP,
factory_no  varchar(255),
vendor_no  varchar(255))
```

Please ignore the data type typos if any.

I want to write a sql query that helps me filter the data per vendor factory. The data to fetch includes the number of orders per vendor factory(a unique group of vendor_no, factory_no), vendor_no, factory_no and the percentage of orders for which fcr_date is greater than completion_date(so percentage = number  of orders  where fcr_date is greater than completion date / count of orders). After  that  i  need  to  filter the data where percentage is greater than say 20%.

I  wrote  the following  query:

```
SELECT  vendor_no As vendor,
        factory_no As factory,
        COUNT(1) as count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fcr_date > completion_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as filter_orders,
    ROUND(filter_orders / count * 100, 4) as  percent  
FROM    @orders
GROUP BY vendor_no,
        factory_no
HAVING percent>20
```

but postgresql complains that  it needs  to  have a column  called percent in table to filter  the  results based on that. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
HAVING ROUND(filter_orders / count * 100, 4) > 20
```

Because `percent` isn't an actual column, you need to give it the calculation to perform the filter.

**Edit**

OK, looking at this further, you've got at least two ways to write this: the one I'd recommend is the first, which involves wrapping in a sub-query (as someone already suggested):

### Option 1

```
SELECT  vendor As vendor,
        factory As factory,
        [count],
        ROUND(filter_orders / count * 100, 4) as  [percent]
FROM
(
    SELECT  vendor_no As vendor,
            factory_no As factory,
            COUNT(1) as count,
            SUM(CASE WHEN fcr_date > completion_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as filter_orders
    FROM    @orders
    GROUP BY vendor_no,
            factory_no
) AS a
WHERE ROUND(filter_orders / count * 100, 4) > 20
```

### Option 2

```
SELECT  vendor_no As vendor,
        factory_no As factory,
        COUNT(1) as count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fcr_date > completion_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as filter_orders,
        ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN fcr_date > completion_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(1) * 100, 4) as  [percent]
FROM    @orders
GROUP BY vendor_no,
        factory_no
HAVING ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN fcr_date > completion_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(1) * 100, 4) > 20
```

Comment: Hey.. POSTGRE wants me to have the columns in  the HAVING clause to  be present in the Group BY. any ideas why it would do so?

Comment: Oops, yes - my bad; try the new examples I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your query with an outer filtering query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  vendor_no As vendor,
            factory_no As factory,
            COUNT(1) as count,
            SUM(CASE WHEN fcr_date > completion_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as filter_orders,
        ROUND(filter_orders / count * 100, 4) as  percent  
    FROM    @orders
    GROUP BY vendor_no,
            factory_no
) x
WHERE percent>20
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't use aliases (like percent) in having clauses or group by clauses.  And by "pretty" I mean Oracle won't let me use aliases in having/group by clauses...not sure about other vendors.

Comment: even POSTGRE wants me to have the columns in HAVING clause  to  be same as those in GROUP BY.. :(

Comment: You can different columns in the having and group by clauses.  You just can't have aliases in either.

SELECT   dd.cost_code, dd.cost_loc, dd.cost_type,
         SUM (dd.item_amount)
    FROM items dd
GROUP BY dd.cost_code, dd.cost_loc, dd.cost_type
  HAVING SUM (dd.item_amount) > 3